# Forms Authentication with AD

Tags: asp.net, webforms, active-directory, forms-authentication

I'm following the steps in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx accurately as far as I know, but am experiencing problems with testing the log in. I'm receiving the error below:

> Configuration Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The container specified in the connection string does not exist.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 34: 
>   Line 35: 
>   Line 36:              type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>   Line 37:              connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
>   Line 38:              connectionUsername="***********"
>
> Source File: C:\Users\mbowman\Dropbox\Cecile project\DoubleEntryForm\DoubleEntryForm\web.config    Line: 36

...and here's the part of the config that it's getting hung up on:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyADMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
         connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
         connectionUsername="*********"
         connectionPassword="********" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

This is the first time I've tried something like this, so I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Edit: the AD connection string is below:

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://frcdom1.fireproof.local/CN=Fireproof,DC=frcdom1,DC=fireproof,DC=local" />
```

Not sure if I have that right. frcdom1 is a domain controller, and fireproof.local is my domain. My users are in an OU called Users under another OU called Fireproof

Comment: Can you please post the ADConnectionString?

Comment: connection string posted at the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the CN part of your AD connection string just doesn't exist in your AD. I bet you have copied the connection string as `CN=Users,DC=your,DC=domain,DC=com`, i.e. you have replaced the domain name but left the user container name (Users).

Consult your actual AD structure and modify your connection string so that it points to a valid container name. Without knowing the exact structure of your AD, it is not possible to tell what container name is valid in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use C# this guide can help you , I connected to Windows server 2003 and 2008, you can get all information the user but the user permissions information this it isn´t avaliable.

[Login Active Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)